# string formed as arrayList to arrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, casting

I have the followings string from the DB **"[["22-1-2017;10:00-19:00"],["22-1-2017;10:00-19:00"]]"**

Is there an easy way to transform the string into an arrayList?

Thanks in advance

Comment: That depends on what your definition of the word "easy" is.  If you have nested structure as you showed us, in general you'd want to use some sort of parser to read it in.

Comment: An ArrayList of what? Strings?

Comment: @OH GOD SPIDERS yes of strings like [["22-1-2017;10:00-19:00"],["22-1-2017;10:00-19:00"]]

Comment: you could use a json parser...

Comment: you want an array containing `{ "22-1-2017;10:00-19:00", "22-1-2017;10:00-19:00" }` at the end ?

Comment: @jValls your example "of strings like [["22-1-2017;10:00-19:00"],["22-1-2017;10:00-19:00"]]" shows List of Lists of String, not List of String. Please clarify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using JSON parser like gson?

```
String jsonArray = "[[\"22-1-2017;10:00-19:00\"],[\"22-1-2017;10:00-19:00\"]]";

Type listType = new TypeToken<List<List<String>>>(){}.getType();
List<List<String>> list = new Gson().fromJson(jsonArray, listType);

System.out.println(list);
```

Output: `[[22-1-2017;10:00-19:00], [22-1-2017;10:00-19:00]]`

Comment: works perfect! Just what I need it simple and effective. I also imported the followings packages for Type and TypeToken: import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;

Answer (score 0):

I got one solution for your problem, if you want the date in an String Array:

```
    String s = "[[\"22-1-2017;10:00-19:00\"],[\"22-1-2017;10:00-19:00\"]]";

    // first remove outter brackets
    s = s.substring(1, s.length());
    s = s.substring(0, s.length()-1);

    // Create a Pattern for getting everything within brackets
    Pattern r = Pattern.compile("\\[(.*?)\\]");
    // Now create matcher object.
    Matcher m = r.matcher(s);

    List<String> l = new ArrayList<>();
    while (m.find()) {
        l.add(m.group(1));
    }
    System.out.println(l);
```

If you want it without the quotations use

```
    Pattern r = Pattern.compile("\\[\"(.*?)\"\\]");
```

Hope this helps

Edit: 
If you use the

```
    Pattern r = Pattern.compile("\\[\"(.*?)\"\\]");
```

you do not need to remove the outer brackets at all, as it already looks for content within:

- opening square brackets with double quotations
- double quotations with closing square brackets

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
String a = "[[\"22-1-2017;10:00-19:00\"],[\"22-1-2017;10:00-19:00\"]]";
String[] b = a.replace("[", "").replace("]", "").replace("\"", "").split(",");
List<String> c = Arrays.asList(b);
```

Output = [22-1-2017;10:00-19:00, 22-1-2017;10:00-19:00]

Comment: assuming that the dates does not contains `[`, `]` nor `"`, it works only if the result must be a flatten `List<String>`, not a `List<List<String>>`

Comment: String.replace() will return the original value if occurrence not found. Is there any reason to flatten the result to List<List<String>> if it could be flatten to List<String>?